# how to run java on website and to get values to html

Tags: java, html, web

i know the question may sound easy to most of you but I am stuck with it.

First of all i like to define what i am trying to achieve.
on eclipse i am running a piece of code that sends some data over specific port, and via html and javascript i am getting those that it's sent and print them on screen.

I have an account from one of free hosting websites.
I want to run my code on that website  e.g mywebsite.blahblah.com/...
and from html file on my computer i want to access that website, get those values produced by java code and print them on screen.

I have no idea where to start.
the codes are

java and html

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

public class GPSServer extends WebSocketServer {

static int port = 9876;

public GPSServer(int port) throws UnknownHostException {
    super(new InetSocketAddress(port));
}

public GPSServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
    super(address);
}

public void sendData(String s) {

    Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
    synchronized (con) {
        for (WebSocket c : con) {
            c.send(s);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket arg0, ClientHandshake arg1) {
    System.out.println(arg0.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress()
            .getHostAddress()
            + " connected to the server!");
}

@Override
public void onClose(WebSocket arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3) {
    System.out.println(arg0 + " disconnected!");
}

@Override
public void onError(WebSocket arg0, Exception arg1) {
    arg1.printStackTrace();
    if (arg0 != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket arg0, String arg1) {
    System.out.println(arg0 + ": " + arg1);

}

public static Runnable sendData() {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebSocketImpl.DEBUG = true;
            GPSServer server;

            try {
                server = new GPSServer(GPSServer.port);
                server.start();

                System.out.println("GPS server started at port: "
                        + server.getPort());

                double longitude = 39.55;
                double latitude = 22.16;
                String lng = Double.toString(longitude);
                String ltd = Double.toString(latitude);
                String all = lng + "-" + ltd;

                while (true) {

                    server.sendData(all);
                    /*
                     * server.sendData(Double.toString(longitude));
                     * System.out.println("longitude sent...");
                     * server.sendData(Double.toString(latitude));
                     * System.out.println("latitude sent...");
                     */
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

    Thread thread = new Thread(GPSServer.sendData());
    thread.start();
}
}
```

--

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{

var lat;
var lng;
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
 {
 alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
 console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
 // Let us open a web socket
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9876/echo");
 ws.onopen = function()
 {
    ws.send("Message to send");
    alert("Message is sent...");


 };







 ws.onmessage = function (evt)  { 

    var partsArray = evt.data.split('-');
    lng=partsArray[0];
    lat=partsArray[1];
    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);

    }; 






 ws.onclose = function() { 
     alert("Connection is closed...");
     console.log("Connection is closed...");
};



  }
  else
  {
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
  <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
<div>
<p id="para"> BASIC HTML!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're very new to all this web development. I haven't studied your code fully but the basic idea is you need a server side scripting language like JSP(of course JSP because you're using Java Code). I hope you know Javascript's basic idea is to use resources on the client's end, or to load data dynamically. So if you're only concerned with displaying some values from server to the client, you can simple make a servlet which will print your data.
Following MVC pattern,

- Controller== Make a servlet which will handle the request made by user(i.e. the link which will show data,basically). Set your Model in this controller once you receive a request(you can decide what to do on GET/POST separately too).
- Model== Make an abstract representation(class of Java) holding all your data that is to be displayed.
- View== Here you'll receive the model. In other words, this will be your HTML. You can use JSP helpers to customize the view, the basic idea is to control HOW DATA WILL BE SHOWN TO THE USER(hence the name View). HTML will be automatically generated at run-time and passed to the user.

Again, I say I'm assuming you're very new to web development. Please let me know if I haven't understood your question well. Enjoy coding.